# Pandas Strings, Apply two methods or more simultaneous

Tags: python, pandas

We have:

```
df['col'].str.startswith('a')
```

and

```
df['col'].str.endswith('b')
```

I trying to do something like that:

```
df['col'].str.startswith('a').str.endswith('b') (it doesn't work)
```

In SQL we do: **LIKE 'a%b'**

We can use this two methods simultaneous in some way?

things like 'abcdef'.upper().startswith('A') work on python, so I was expecting that will work on pandas too, that`s saves a lot of time to code.

Comment: use regex instead of string methods

Comment: Did you try: df[df['col'].str.startswith('a') & df['col'].str.endswith('b')] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) to do this with a single function call?

```
df['col'].str.match(r'a.*b$')
```

This will match all strings that start with "a" AND end with "b".

---

To answer the broader question of how to combine conditions, you would do that using the logical AND (`&`) operator.

```
df['col'].str.startswith('a') & df['col'].str.endswith('b')
```

This is a non-regex solution, but with two function calls, so your mileage may vary.